# conditional probability and expectation of random variables

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

It is given that $E[Y/A]$ where $A = {X \in C}, C \in B(R) $; Want to indicate how to compute  $E[Y/A]$. Here $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint density $f(x,y)$. Any ideas will be very helpful on this problem.

I started doing as follows;

$E[Y/A] = E[Y/X \in C] $. 
I don't know how to continue from here.
Thank you.

Comment: The situation depends on whether $A$ has positive probability or not. There is a very simple formula if it does have positive probability, but if it doesn't then this formula gives the useless answer $0/0$.

Comment: Better to use $\mid$ than $/$

Answer (score 1):

The conditional expectation is $$\mathbb{E}[Y \mid X \in C] = \dfrac{\displaystyle \int_{y\in \mathbb{R}}\int_{x \in C} y f(x,y) \, dx\, dy}{\displaystyle \int_{y\in \mathbb{R}}\int_{x \in C} f(x,y) \, dx\, dy}$$  though as Ian says there is an issue if the denominator is zero.

Comment: Thank you.Is it same as saying $1/{P(X \in C)} \quad \int_{X \in C} Y dp? $. 


$E[Y | X \in C]$ exists if ${P(X \in C)} \geq 0$ right?

Comment: If the denominator is $0$ but $f_X$ is not identically $0$ on $C$ (which would make conditioning on $X\in C$ meaningless), wouldn't a simple $E(Y|X\in C)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}E(Y|X\in C_\epsilon)$ work for $C_\epsilon=\cup_{x\in C}B_x(\epsilon)$?